# Pandas - Fill with other column if the field is NaT (Null)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

On Pandas Dataframes-

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
ID         date1            date2             date3
 0           NaT              NaT        2019-02-28
 1           NaT       2019-11-10        2019-04-09
 2           NaT              NaT        2019-05-21
 3    2019-12-06       2019-12-05        2019-12-27
 4    2019-11-18       2019-11-18        2019-12-20
```

I want to add another field in the dataframe in order to have an output like this:

```
ID        date1          date2            date3          date4
 0          NaT            NaT       2019-02-28     2019-02-28
 1          NaT     2019-11-10       2019-04-09     2019-11-10
 2          NaT            NaT       2019-05-21     2019-05-21
 3   2019-12-06     2019-12-05       2019-12-27     2019-12-06
 4   2019-11-18     2019-11-18       2019-12-20     2019-11-18
```

In order,

> The date4 will be populated by the date3 if date2 and date1 not populated.
>
> The date4 will be populated by the date2 if date2 and date3 populated.
>
> The date4 will be populated by the date1 if date1, date2 and date3 populated.

Do you have an idea on how achieve this ?

I tried the `fillna` but not really successfull.

Comment: can you send dict version of your dataframe using ```df.to_dict(orient='records')```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use back filling missing values and then select first column by positions by [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
df['date4'] = df[['date1','date2','date3']].bfill(axis=1).iloc[:, 0]
```

Or use [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) or [`Series.combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.combine_first.html):

```
df['date4'] = df['date1'].fillna(df['date2']).fillna(df['date3'])
print (df)
   ID      date1      date2      date3      date4
0   0        NaT        NaT 2019-02-28 2019-02-28
1   1        NaT 2019-11-10 2019-04-09 2019-11-10
2   2        NaT        NaT 2019-05-21 2019-05-21
3   3 2019-12-06 2019-12-05 2019-12-27 2019-12-06
4   4 2019-11-18 2019-11-18 2019-12-20 2019-11-18
```

Comment: I would have used chaining, and I like the bfill option, +1

Comment: I like the bfill option... Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can replace NaN values like this:

```
df['date4']=np.where(df['date1'].isna(),df['date2'],df['date1'])
df['date4']=np.where(df['date4'].isna(),df['date3'],df['date3'])
```

There are some cases you didnt consider (like what if date1 is not NaN but date2 is) but those all can be dealt with similarly.

Answer (score 1):

I'd personally use a loop so it's clear what's happening, and more maintainable. Here's an example. Using your listed conditions for 'date4' doesn't fill all with an entry.

```
# required modules
import pandas as pd
import itertools

# create a data frame
d = {'ID': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], 
     'date1': [None, None, None, '2019-12-06', '2019-11-18'], 
     'date2': [None, '2019-11-10', None, '2019-12-05', '2019-11-18'], 
     'date3': ['2019-02-28', '2019-04-09', '2019-05-21', '2019-12-27', '2019-12-20']}

dat = pd.DataFrame(d)

# make date4
date4 = []
for index, row in dat.iterrows():
    if row['date2'] and row['date1'] == None:
        date4.append(row['date3'])
    elif row['date2'] and row['date3'] != None:
        date4.append(row['date2'])
    elif row['date1'] and row['date2'] and row['date3'] != None:
        date4.append(row['date1'])
    else:
        date4.append(None)

# append to df
dat['date4'] = date4
```